# Find highest power dividing an even integer into an odd integer

Tags: exponentiation, integers, natural-numbers

Got some even integer $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$

Given this expression: $n\over2^x$

Need to find the highest power, i.e. $x$ in the above (exponent value). So that the result always gives an odd number.

Is there a formula for finding this exponent value in base-10, or is it more complex than this. I need something simple.

Comment: See [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29828/greatest-power-of-two-dividing-an-integer).

Comment: I allready have a base-2 representation though, and thats the interesting part in that thread for me. But I need a simpler one in base-10.

Comment: What do you mean with "something simple" ? Isn't repeated division by $2$ until we arrive at an odd number simple enough ?

Comment: I mean direct division. Not repeated.